# Compilation error in ASP.NET MVC4 BigShelf sample SPA solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, single-page-application

Just trying out the sample for the MVC4 Single Page Application. The BigShelf project is [here](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/spa-samples/sample-bigshelf-application)

But when I try to run this, I get the following error after logging in. I'm not sure what is wrong.

> Compilation Error Description: An error occurred during the
>   compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please
>   review the following specific error details and modify your source
>   code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0012: The type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'EntityFramework,
>   Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 22:      Line 23:         $(function () { Line 24:
>   upshot.metadata(@(Html.Metadata()));
>   Line 25:  Line 26:             ko.applyBindings(new
>   BigShelf.CatalogViewModel({
>
> Source File: d:\Visual Studio Projects\ASP.NET Single Page Application
>   (SPA) BigShelf\C#\BigShelf\Views\Home\Index.cshtml    Line: 24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the EntityFramework reference and referencing the latest (4.3.1) solved the problem for me.